# Is it crazy to use Azure for Intranet Site containing sensitive data

Tags: azure

is it absolute insanity to start hosting new intranet web apps in Azure using an on-premise sql instance and ADFS 2.0 (via Azure Connect)? My concern is that instead of the site being behind a firewall, being hosted in Azure has the side effect of anyone who discovers the URL can hack away at it.

Thoughts???

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's good news on the ADFS 2.0 front.

Authentication with ADFS 2.0 requires the client's browser to be able to communicate with the application server and the ADFS 2.0 server. There's no direct connection between Azure and ADFS 2.0.

If you make sure that your ADFS 2.0 server is only accessible from your corporate network or via VPN, you've already closed one of the major attack vectors; no brute force or dictionary attack is going to help a bad guy in if they can't connect to your authentication service.

As well as all-important security, take into consideration the bandwidth costs for your hybrid cloud solution. You'll be paying for every byte to and from your SQL Server.

Comment: This IS good news. So what you are saying is a bad guy at Starbucks will never be able to authenticate because they do not have a line of sight to the ADFS instllation, but someone within the organization does. This more or less makes it an intranet app...more or less.

Comment: That's precisely what I'm saying, Mike. You still have to deal with the fact that an application running on an 'untrusted' platform is accessing your sensitive data, but authentication is in the bag ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Do their trial.... and see how fast you can get up to speed with locking the security down.  Hey, at least your not asking about Amazon's Cloud.  Don't do it because it is the cool thing to do.  Research the pro's and con's.  Gmail is a cloud based Email service that I and many have used for years.  All in all it works pretty well.  The future is more cloud, where more businesses have dumb terminals with virtual use of cloud services.  The personal pc is bound to become make less important.

Microsoft has invested a lot into Azure, if you follow their security guidelines you should be just fine.